# Accessing a css file with jQuery (or other library)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I've already searched for how to get the css file and found that you can use $.get('file path', callback) to actually get the file.

First question. I can get the content of the file, but it is a long string. Is there a method to search that file? For example, if there was a particular selector in the CSS file, can I use jQuery or some other library to retrieve the styles in a convenient form.

Second question. The reason why I want this is because I'd like to do some animations with data gotten out of the CSS file. First of all, is this possible? Second, is this recommended?

Comment: The right thing to do would be to load the css and then apply appropriate css classes for animation when required.

Comment: Oh, I wasn't aware that jQuery could animate directly with classes. Sorry bout this.

Comment: @BringMeAnother It's not jQuery doing the animations. It's CSS. You only use jQuery to apply the appropriate CSS class.

Answer (score 0):

Once you retrieve the file, you need to parse it. I'm not sure if there are any CSS parsing engines out there, but if there are, they're all based off of regex expressions. If you're looking for something in particular, it might be wise to just write your own regex pattern for it.

As for doing animations... yes? I don't know exactly what you need to the data for or what you plan to do with it, but yes, you can always animate something. I can't make any recommendations because I don't know **exactly** what you're trying to do.

Comment: All CSS rules are already available in `document.styleSheets` as a [`CSSRuleList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSRuleList). However, I think this method is really not what the OP wants.

Comment: That's assuming the stylesheet he wants is already loaded (it probably is from the sound of it). Which browsers support `document.styleSheets`?

Comment: All of them. It's DOM Level 2.

Comment: Addendum: Seems IE8 and earlier [lack the `CSSRuleList`](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_css.html) though.